# Cannot change viewport height of sidebar for scrollbar

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css, scrollbar

This is my code:

```
 <body className="flex h-[100vw] flex-1 flex-col">
        <div className="flex flex-1 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">
            <Menu />
            <div className="h-[100vh] flex-1 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll">
              <main>{children}</main>
            </div>
            <div className="basis-1/3">Sidebar</div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </body>
```

[Image to better explain my objective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMlsJ.png)

RED: the scrollbar for MAIN, all good (scrollbar starts at top viewport and ends bottom viewport)
YELLOW: the scrollbar of the browser, all gooed (when scrolling down you go to bottom of page)
**BLUE: here is the problem, bad. When scrolling down it goes to the end of the sidebar. But I want that it behaves like RED, meaning scrollbar should start at top viewport and end bottom viewport). I tried to set the Sidebar component to `h-[100vh]` but nothing changed.**

Everything else in my code I like to keep, functionality is exactly what I want, only Sidebar and BLUE scrollbar makes me unhappy.